# Formatting Unity data for communication with a REST API

Tags: unity, data-structure, json

I am pretty new to unity but I am not new to programming. I am building a Hololens application in Unity 2017.2 and it communicates with a REST api that I built. I am using Unity as a front end more or less and it manages my state. Coming from the web developement world, I have my server converting my models into JSON and I am sending that as a response. For the most part, it works well but since Unity works on an older version of C#, I am having issues working with the JSON data, mainly if the data type is not a string, int, float, or double. For example, if my model contains a date data type I am having issues converting it back into a c# model or even arrays are proving to be a pain. I don’t want to rely on unity packages too much as most I have tried don’t do what I need but I am open to any good ones if you know of any.

My question is, what is the best way to send data from my API to Unity? Should I send xml or a csv instead? Or even a more C# native approach? (If that makes sense)

Comment: There is never just one best way. Only the way which works best for your particular project. There is a myriad of different data exchange formats. Which one fits you depends on your data.

Comment: I found a solid solution for me last night. I posted it below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find a solid solution at [this link](https://codehandbook.org/c-object-xml/)

I put the static method in my server

```
public static string GetXMLFromObject(object o)
{
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    XmlTextWriter tw = null;
    try
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(o.GetType());
        tw = new XmlTextWriter(sw);
        serializer.Serialize(tw, o);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Handle Exception Code
    }
    finally
    {
        sw.Close();
        if (tw != null)
        {
            tw.Close();
        }
    }
    return sw.ToString();
}
```

And all worked well.

And then the method for sending the response called the function like in the link

```
[HttpGet]
public string GetData(){
    Employee emp = new Employee();
    emp.FirstName = "Code";
    emp.LastName = "Handbook";
    string xml = GetXMLFromObject(emp);
    return xml;
}
```

And in my Unity C# script, I parsed the response using the second static method given in the link but two changes had to be made.

```
public static Object ObjectToXML(string xml, Type objectType)
{
    StringReader strReader = null;
    XmlSerializer serializer = null;
    XmlTextReader xmlReader = null;
    Object obj = null;
    try
    {
        strReader = new StringReader(xml);
        serializer = new XmlSerializer(objectType);
        xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(strReader);
        obj = serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        //Handle Exception Code
    }
    finally
    {
        if (xmlReader != null)
        {
            xmlReader.Close();
        }
        if (strReader != null)
        {
            strReader.Close();
        }
    }
    return obj;
}
```

The changes were easy enough to implement, they were: 
Unity C# does not support `XmlReader` using the System namespace so I had to add a conditional statement to the `using` statement. You can read more about it in the [official unity documentation here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/windowsstore-missingtypes.html)

```
#if NETFX_CORE
using XmlReader = WinRTLegacy.Xml.XmlReader;
#else
using XmlReader = System.Xml.XmlReader;
#endif
```

The second change was that `strReader.Close()` does not exist in the Unity C# scripting.

Change this:

```
if (strReader != null)
{
    strReader.Close();
}
```

To this:

```
if (strReader != null)
{
    strReader.Dispose();
}
```

I found that solution in [a forum here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/system-xml-xmlreader-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-close.232296/)

One last thing to note, `Object` was giving me some issues so I had to add the `System` to it. `System.Object` although Visual Studio said I did not need it, errors were thrown with out it. The final method looked like this:

```
public static System.Object ObjectToXML(string xml, Type objectType)
{
    StringReader strReader = null;
    XmlSerializer serializer = null;
    XmlTextReader xmlReader = null;
    System.Object obj = null;
    try
    {
        strReader = new StringReader(xml);
        serializer = new XmlSerializer(objectType);
        xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(strReader);
        obj = serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        //Handle Exception Code
    }
    finally
    {
        if (xmlReader != null)
        {
            xmlReader.Close();
        }
        if (strReader != null)
        {
            strReader.Dispose();
        }
    }
    return obj;
}
```

And to use it, I did this:

```
// handled response above
string xml = response.text;
Employee emp = new Employee();

try{
    System.Object obj = ObjectToXML(xml,typeof(Employee));
    emp = (Employee)obj;
}
catch (Exception ex){
    Debug.Log(ex.message);
    emp = null;
}
finally{
    if(emp != null){
        // do stuff
    }
    else{
        // handle error
    }
}
```

This was a lot easier than trying to parse JSON and I am able to throw the XML right into an object. The actual object I used was more complex than the `Employee` example and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve found using simplejson as an easy way to handle json responses

https://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/SimpleJSON

For the setup, you just need to place the simplejson file in a project folder. 
When handling responses, you can access the data like this:

```
jsonresponse["players"][2]["items"][5].Value;
```

for string values, and:

```
jsonresponse["players"][1]["life"].AsInt;
```

for int values and so on.

It solves the problem of having to predefine the expected json response data beforehand.